# Por que minha classe só retorna NULL?

Tags: php

Gente, onde ta o problema? Instanciando diretamente as classes `validaNome` e `validaSobrenome` elas funcionam, agora na classe `msgContato` elas retornam `NULL`, onde estou errando?

**validaNome**

```
class validaNome {

    public $ico_warning, $ico_success;
    
    public function setNome($nome) {
        
        if (empty($nome)) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome está vazio.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) < 3) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) > 25) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
        else :
            return $nome;
        endif;

    }

}
```

**validaSobrenome**

```
class validaSobrenome {

    public $ico_warning, $ico_success;
    
    public function setSobrenome($sobrenome) {
        
        if (empty($sobrenome)) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome está vazio.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($sobrenome) < 3) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($sobrenome) > 25) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
        else :
            return $sobrenome;
        endif;

    }

}
```

**msgContato**

```
class msgContato {

    private $v_nome, $p_nome, $v_sobrenome, $p_sobrenome, $v_email, $p_email, $v_assunto, $p_assunto, $v_mensagem, $p_mensagem, $crud;
    
    public function getContato($nome, $sobrenome) {
        
        $this->v_nome = new validaNome;
        $this->v_sobrenome = new validaSobrenome;

        $this->v_nome->setNome(''.$nome.'');
        $this->v_sobrenome->setSobrenome(''.$sobrenome.'');

    }

}

$a = new msgContato;
var_dump($a->getContato('aaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));
```

Comment: Seu código está errado em todos os lados.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic como assim?

Comment: Métodos não fazem o que espera não tem return etc. O que você pretende fazer?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic opa desculpa a demora, fiquei sem internet, então ai seria uma simples validação pra um form de contato

Comment: Veja o retorno do @Augusto Vasques, sua classe não está NULL. Outra coisa, está confuso e muito estranho a maneira que estruturou suas classes para uma simples validação.Você criou 2 classes para 2 validações, por que não criar somente uma classe apenas ? Melhor, por que não colocar as validações somente nos métodos de atribuição do `$v_nome` e `$v_sobrenome` se é realmente só isso que deseja validar ? Há N maneiras de fazer o que deseja, reestruture tudo que será melhor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, como já comentei na sua pergunta, está muito estranho a forma que você estruturou suas classes.

Referente a sua pergunta, você está dando um `var_dump`em `$a->getContato('$a->getContato('aaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));` e isso não faz sentido pois não é retornado nada neste método.

Conforme já dito pelo @Augusto Vasques você teria que retornar algo ou até mesmo dar o `var_dump` depois de chamar o `getContato()`.

Mesmo assim não deixa de estar confuso, sugiro que reestruture suas classes, há N maneiras de se fazer isso que deseja, vou deixar um exemplo abaixo.

```
<?php     
    class msgContato {

        private $nomecompleto; 
        private $email;
        private $telefone;
        //...
        
        public function getContato($nome, $sobrenome) {

            $this->nomecompleto = new NomeCompleto();

            $this->nomecompleto->setNome(''.$nome.'');
            $this->nomecompleto->setSobrenome(''.$sobrenome.'');
            
            return $this;
        }
    }
    
    class NomeCompleto{
        private $nome;
        private $sobrenome;
        
        public function setNome($nome) {

            if (empty($nome)) :
                $this->nome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome está vazio.</b>';
            else if (strlen($nome) < 3) :
                $this->nome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
            else if (strlen($nome) > 25) :
                $this->nome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
            else :
                $this->nome = $nome;
            endif;
        }
        
        public function setSobrenome($sobrenome) {

            if (empty($sobrenome)) :
                $this->sobrenome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome está vazio.</b>';
            else if (strlen($sobrenome) < 3) :
                $this->sobrenome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
            else if (strlen($sobrenome) > 25) :
                $this->sobrenome = '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
            else :
                $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
            endif;

        }
    }
    
    $a = new msgContato();
    var_dump($a->getContato('aaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'));
?>
```

Veja o código funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/cZ76px)

Answer (score 5):

Sua pergunta é:

> Porque minha classe só retorna NULL?

Sua classe não retorna nulo. Quem retorna nulo é o método `getContato($nome, $sobrenome)` da classe `msgContato`

Vamos as evidências:

Declarado as mesmas classes que usou em sua pergunta:

```
class validaNome {

    public $ico_warning, $ico_success;

    public function setNome($nome) {

        if (empty($nome)) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome está vazio.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) < 3) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) > 25) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
        else :
            return $nome;
        endif;

    }

}

class validaSobrenome {

    public $ico_warning, $ico_success;

    public function setSobrenome($sobrenome) {

        if (empty($sobrenome)) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome está vazio.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($sobrenome) < 3) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($sobrenome) > 25) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
        else :
            return $sobrenome;
        endif;

    }

}

class msgContato {

    private $v_nome, $p_nome, $v_sobrenome, $p_sobrenome, $v_email, $p_email, $v_assunto, $p_assunto, $v_mensagem, $p_mensagem, $crud;

    public function getContato($nome, $sobrenome) {

        $this->v_nome = new validaNome;
        $this->v_sobrenome = new validaSobrenome;

        $this->v_nome->setNome(''.$nome.'');
        $this->v_sobrenome->setSobrenome(''.$sobrenome.'');

          
    }

}
```

Vamos criar uma instancia da classe `msgContato`:

```
$Contato = new msgContato;
```

Agora vamos fazer o dump da instancia `$Contato`:

```
var_dump($Contato);
```

Que resultará em:

```bash
object(msgContato)#1 (11) {
  ["v_nome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_nome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_sobrenome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_sobrenome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_email":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_email":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_assunto":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_assunto":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_mensagem":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_mensagem":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["crud":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

O que significa que sua classe não é nula.

Agora se fizemos o dump do método `getContato($nome, $sobrenome)`:

```
var_dump($Contato->getContato("Stack", "Oveflow"));
```

O resulatado será:

```
NULL
```

Pois o método `getContato($nome, $sobrenome)` não possui valor de retorno.

Para alterar esse comportamento modifique o método `getContato($nome, $sobrenome)` adicionando a palavra chave `return` mais um valor para ser retornado:

```
    public function getContato($nome, $sobrenome) {

        $this->v_nome = new validaNome;
        $this->v_sobrenome = new validaSobrenome;

        $this->v_nome->setNome(''.$nome.'');
        $this->v_sobrenome->setSobrenome(''.$sobrenome.'');

        //Essa função retornava NULL, agora retornará a própria instancia
        return $this;

    }
```

Cujo o dump será:

```
object(msgContato)#1 (11) {
  ["v_nome":"msgContato":private]=>
  object(validaNome)#2 (2) {
    ["ico_warning"]=>
    NULL
    ["ico_success"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["p_nome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_sobrenome":"msgContato":private]=>
  object(validaSobrenome)#3 (2) {
    ["ico_warning"]=>
    NULL
    ["ico_success"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["p_sobrenome":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_email":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_email":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_assunto":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_assunto":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["v_mensagem":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["p_mensagem":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
  ["crud":"msgContato":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Então, seu código não aceita nomes como Ana, Eno,Lia e etc, devido os 3 caracteres, mas vamos lá.
Utilize esta função no lugar da sua **setNome**

```
function setNome($nome) {

    if (empty($nome)) {
     return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome está vazio.</b>';
    } else if (strlen($nome) <= 3) {
        return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
    } elseif (strlen($nome) >= 26) {
        return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
    }else {
        return $nome;
    }

}
```

Utilize esta como sua função **setSobrenome**

```
function setSobrenome($sobrenome) {

    if (empty($sobrenome)) {
        return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome está vazio.</b>';
    }elseif (strlen($sobrenome) <= 3) {
        return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
    } elseif (strlen($sobrenome) >= 26) {
        return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Sobrenome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';
    }   else {
        return $sobrenome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu defini 26 caracteres para poder ser usado até 25 caracteres

Answer (score 2):

Você está invocando a função `getContato` da classe `msgContato` e a função apenas seta os nomes, não tem retorno nem nenhuma outra ação, então o esperado é não retornada mesmo (ou null).

Faça a função fazer alguma coisa, tipo retornar o que foi setado, assim:

```
class msgContato {

    private $v_nome, $p_nome, $v_sobrenome, $p_sobrenome, $v_email, $p_email, $v_assunto, $p_assunto, $v_mensagem, $p_mensagem, $crud;

    public function getContato($nome, $sobrenome) {

        $this->v_nome = new validaNome;
        $this->v_sobrenome = new validaSobrenome;

        $retorno_nome = $this->v_nome->setNome(''.$nome.''); //recebe o retorno de setNome
        $retorno_sobrenome = $this->v_sobrenome->setSobrenome(''.$sobrenome.''); //recebe o retorno de setSobrenome

        //retorna o resultado obtido em setNome e setSobrenome
        return [
            "nome" => $retorno_nome,
            "sobrenome" => $retorno_sobrenome
        ];
    }
}
```

Dessa forma que escrevi acima, a função irá retornar o nome e sobrenome que foram passados

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe **validaNome** Não trata nomes que possuem entre 4 e 24 caracteres. Por isso retorna NULL

Sua classe **validaSobrenome** Não trata sobrenomes que possuem entre 4 e 24 caracteres. Por isso retorna NULL

tente retornar o valor do nome com um else final tipo assim:

```
class validaNome {

    public $ico_warning, $ico_success;

    public function setNome($nome) {

        if (empty($nome)) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome está vazio.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) < 3) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome tem que ter mais de 3 caracteres.</b>';
        elseif (strlen($nome) > 25) :
            return '<b class="ico_msg error"><i class="fas fa-engine-warning"></i> Nome no maximo 25 caracteres.</b>';

        else:
             return $nome;

        endif;  

    }

}
```

Comment: nada feito, ja tinha colocado o else antes e nada, realmente nao consigo saber pq retorna NULL